# Calculating the determinants of polynomially many submatrices

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

**Question:**

I have a $n\times n$ matrix $M_{ij}$ and I can form a submatrix $S$ by restricting the indexes $a\leq i,j\leq b$. This only includes contiguous subamtrices, of which there are a number $n(n-1)/2$ and does not include all minors, of which there a number $2^n$.

If I want to calculate all such submatrix determinants. Can I do better than the $O(n^{4.373})$ time of calculating them all sequentially?

**Initial thoughts:**

I had a look at the different calculation methods which I am familiar with:

Since I need such a large number I initially thought row expansion might be useful, but since this calculates the determinants of all minors (rather than just contiguous ones) it takes $O(2^n)$ time.

Additionally I suspect factorisation methods to be unlikely to be useful due to the challenge of keeping track of how row operations affect the different determinants to be evaluated.

Comment: If you don't care about division by $0$ you could use [Dodgeson condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodgson_condensation) at cost $O(n^3).$